# jquery UI tabs - any tutorials

Tags: jquery, user-interface

Are there any more extensive tutorials / documentations on the tabs widget? http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs doesn't seem to cover or explain advanced features. I'm at a loss for how to dynamically add and remove tabs, for instance. Should I be studying some more background to the jquery UI?

Answer (score 1):

A small collection :

http://jqueryfordesigners.com/jquery-tabs/
http://apricotstudios.wordpress.com/2008/08/29/jquery-tabs-tutorial/
http://justintadlock.com/archives/2007/11/07/how-to-create-tabs-using-jquery
http://stilbuero.de/jquery/tabs/

Comment: Thanks for the effort...but I've already seen 3 out of 4 of those. They don't seem to get much past the basics.

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically add/remove tabs using the [add](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#method-add) and [remove](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#method-remove) methods. Calling those methods will trigger their corresponding [add](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#event-add) and [remove](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#event-remove) events.